# how to count multiple columns in oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle

From the below item table, i need to get the count of each item_value period if the item_value_period is = '0.4'.

[image: item table]

Expected result:

[image]

Comment: I cannot figure out what the expected results has to do with the rule you describe.

Comment: hi @GordonLinoff, in the expected result, I am only taking the records where item_value_period1 or item_value_period2 or item_value_period3 has a value of 0.4 and grouping the result at the end. also doing a count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select item_id, item_name,
       max(case when item_value_period1 = 0.4 then item_value_period1 end),
       sum(case when item_value_period1 = 0.4 then 1 else 0 end),
       max(case when item_value_period2 = 0.4 then item_value_period2 end),
       sum(case when item_value_period2 = 0.4 then 1 else 0 end),
       max(case when item_value_period3 = 0.4 then item_value_period3 end),
       sum(case when item_value_period3 = 0.4 then 1 else 0 end)
from t
group by item_id, item_name;
```

Comment: can you please explain why you are using max and sum? @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @Mona . . . Because I think those return the values that you want.